# Strange behaviour ScaleAnimation setFillAfter(true) / false

Tags: android, animation, matrix, touch, imageview

we are using a TouchImageView and want to implement a onDoubleTap zoom ...
so far so good.

The problem is:

if we apply a **scale animation** and set **setFillAfter(false)**, in an AnimationListener.onAnimationEnd, we apply the **correct matrix** to the imageview, and **everything works as expected** (scrolling, other zoom gestures, etc).
-> but - you see a small flackering on the screen (what is understandable - because the animation jumps back to the beginning and afterwards the matrix changes will be applied)

**on the other side**, if **setFillEnabled(true)**, the animation looks great, no flackering, but somehow the **view is completely messed up**, at first everything looks great, but the **max and min zoom levels are completely messed up** - you cannot zoom out to initial zoom anymore, and also **moving the picture doesnt work** as expected - borders are false? something like that)

**So our question(s) ;)?**

- What does a ScaleAnimation with setFillAfter(true) actually do?
- Does it change the size of the (complete) imageview?
- What goes wrong :/ ?

as always thanks a lot for your help :=)
cheers,

//BTW: this happens in all **android versions <= 4**, on 4.1 the described problem doesnt occur and everyhting works as expected.

**---------------**
**update:**
so the current code is like this, works, (no problem in zoom anymore) but has a small "flickering" between setting the matrix and clearing the animation (although) the code shows, that it should apply the matrix **-before-** the animation gets cleaned, so i was hopeing for a seamless transition... 
**thx for your reply!**

```
            Log.v("TouchImageView", "Zoom in");
            ScaleAnimation zoomIn = new ScaleAnimation(saveScale, SCALE_DOUBLE_TAP, saveScale, SCALE_DOUBLE_TAP, width / 2, height / 2);
            zoomIn.setDuration(200);
            zoomIn.setFillAfter(true);
            zoomIn.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    isAnimating = true;
                    saveScale = SCALE_DOUBLE_TAP;
                    right = width * saveScale - width - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);
                    bottom = height * saveScale - height - (2 * redundantYSpace * saveScale);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    isAnimating = false;
                    matrix.postScale(SCALE_DOUBLE_TAP, SCALE_DOUBLE_TAP, width / 2, height / 2);
                    matrix.getValues(matrixValues);
                    setImageMatrix(matrix);
                    clearAnimation();
                }
            });


            startAnimation(zoomIn);
```

Answer (score 5):

`setFillAfter(true)` will fake that it is actually scaled, I recommend using it in conjunction with your matrix scaling. On the animation end apply the matrix and call `clearAnimation()` on the `View` that the animation was applied on. This should fix the flicker.

Comment: great tip, thanks a lot for explaining :) as soon as i start to work on monday morning :=) i'll let u know it it works.. but it sounds as if it would be the "secret answer ;D"

Comment: hey, just applied your changes and it somehow "works..." but now, due to clearAnimation clears the animation, I get a small "flickering" on the screen, you see that the animation gets cleared, and then the matrix gets applied, i updated the post above, maybe you got any clue how to avoid this :)